# Connecting to dbus over tcp

Tags: python, dbus

I wrote a simple python program to play and pause banshee music player.
While its working on my own machine, I have trouble doing it to a remote computer, connected to the same router (LAN).
I edited the session.conf of the remote machine, to add this line:

```
<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=12434</listen>
```

and here is my program:

```
    import dbus


    bus_obj=dbus.bus.BusConnection("tcp:host=localhost,port=12434")
    proxy_object=bus_obj.get_object('org.bansheeproject.Banshee',                              
    '/org/bansheeproject/Banshee/PlayerEngine')

    playerengine_iface=dbus.Interface(proxy_object,
    dbus_interface='org.bansheeproject.Banshee.PlayerEngine')

    var=0

    while (var!="3"):
        var=raw_input("\nPress\n1 to play\n2 to pause\n3 to exit\n")


            if var=="1":
                print "playing..."
                playerengine_iface.Play()

            elif var=="2":
                print "pausing"
                playerengine_iface.Pause()
```

This is what i get when i try to execute it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbus3.py", line 4, in <module>
    bus_obj=dbus.bus.BusConnection("tcp:host=localhost,port=12434")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 125, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket "localhost:12434" Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong here?
should i edit /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py

UPDATE:

ok, here is the deal 
when i add

```
<listen>tcp:host=192.168.1.7,port=12434</listen>
```

to to /etc/dbus-1/session.conf, then reboot, hoping it would start listening on reboot,
It never boots. It gets stuck on loading screen and occasionally, a black screen with the following text flashes:

```
Pulseaudio Configured For Per-user Sessions Saned Disabled;edit/etc/default/saned
```

so, when i go ctrl+alt+f1 , change session.conf to original state and reboot, it boots properly.

Whats all that about?
How can I make dbus daemon listen for tcp connections, without encountering problems?

Comment: default (ubuntu). Sorry, i have close to zero knowledge when it comes to networking, should i configure the iptable to allow the connection? I thought iptable allows everything by default

Comment: Useful network commands: `netstat -na`, `lsof -ni`, `tcpdump -n -i eth0` and `iptables -nvL`. I think using a combination of those will tell you if your process is listening at all and if yes if it's somehow blocked. Good Luck!

Comment: you can forward tcp packets using `socat` to local unix socket - that way you don't need to restart dbus daemon. Also, try `tcp:host=0.0.0.0,port=12434` - this will bind listening socket to all interfaces. (check if its actually listening after restart - `telnet 192.168.1.7 12434`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I recently needed to set this up, and discovered that the trick is: *order matters* for the `<listen>` elements in `session.conf`. You should make sure the TCP element occurs first. Bizarre, I know, but true, at least for my case. (I see *exactly* the same black screen behavior if I reverse the order and put the UNIX socket `<listen>` element first.)

Also, prepending the TCP `<listen>` tag is necessary, but not sufficient. To make remote D-Bus connections via TCP work, you need to do three things:

1. Add a `<listen>` tag above the UNIX one, similar to this:

   ```
   <listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=55556,family=ipv4</listen>
   <listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>
   ```
2. Add a line (right below the `<listen>` tags is fine) that says:

   ```
   <auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
   ```
3. Add another line below these that says:

   ```
   <allow_anonymous/>
   ```

The `<auth>` tag should be added in addition to any other `<auth>` tags that may be contained in your `session.conf`. In summary, your `session.conf` should contain a snippet that looks like this:

```
<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=55556,family=ipv4</listen>
<listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>

<auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
<allow_anonymous/>
```

After doing these three things, you should be able to connect to the session bus remotely. Here's how it looks when specifying a remote connection in [D-Feet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet/):

[image: D-Feet screen capture]

Note that, if you want to connect to the system bus, too, you need to make similar changes to `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf`, but specify a *different* TCP port, for example 55557. (Oddly enough, the element order appears not to matter in this case.)

The only weird behavior I've noticed in this configuration is that running Desktop apps with `sudo` (e.g., `sudo gvim`) tends to generate errors or fail outright saying "No D-BUS daemon running". But this is something I need to do so rarely that it hardly matters.

If you want to send to a remote machine using `dbus-send`, you need to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` accordingly, e.g., to something like:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=55556,family=ipv4
```

This works even if the bus you want to send to is actually the *system* bus of the remote machine, as long as the setting matches the TCP `<listen>` tag in `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` on the target. (Thanks to [Martin Vidner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684133/martin-vidner) for this tip. Until I stumbled across his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944458/dbus-send-to-remote-machine), I didn't believe `dbus-send` supported remote operation.)

**UPDATE**: If you're using systemd (and want to access the system bus), you might also need to add a line saying `ListenStream=55557` to `/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket`, like so:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
ListenStream=55557  # <-- Add this line
```

**UPDATE2**: Thanks to @altagir for pointing out that [recent versions of D-Bus](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/1.6.12-0ubuntu5) will enable [AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page) mediation on systems where it's available, so you may also need to add `<apparmor mode="disabled"/>` to `session.conf`/`system.conf` for these instructions to work.

Comment: Just an FYI, I needed something like this for mine to work (note the binding and setting of family): <listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=55884,family=ipv4</listen>

Comment: Thanks, @Shorin. I updated my answer to contain the `bind` and `family` key/values pairs.  I don't think they're required in all cases (they weren't in mine), and the values may need to be adjusted for different systems, but including them probably makes the answer more complete and helpful to others. :-)

Comment: Btw, I tried this on an Android device. It hangs on reboot. Needed to flash to get working again.

Comment: If you are struggling to get dbus running on Microsoft's Windows subsystem for linux, this answer will actually help.

Comment: I don't understand how my python dbbus-client would know where the target bus is on the network. Shouldn't there be an IP address of the remote target specified somewhere in the client app?

Comment: @TusharVazirani: You can use the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable to specify the remote target, i.e., run it using something like `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=192.168.1.17,bind=*,port=55556,family=ipv4 ./my_python_app.py`. (NOTE: As mentioned in my answer, this works even if the bus you're connecting to is actually the _system_ bus of the remote machine—provided its `system.conf` is configured to allow connections via TCP.)

Comment: I am using these settings but I cannot receive any signals from my remote application. Do these settings work for receiving signals as well?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, using wireshark, and netstat i'm able to see that my python app is able to connect to interface and call, but i'm getting back DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied :( Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 7):

since dbus 1.6.12 (e.g. kubuntu 13.10), your connection will also be rejected unless you add to your dbus config file  (either /etc/dbus-1/*mybus*.conf or the interface requiring remote access i.e. system.d/*my.interface.conf*)

```
<apparmor mode="disabled"/>
```

**UPDATE:** After struggling to create a apparmor profile allowing the service to connect to the custom dbus-daemon, it seems the connection is always rejected due to a bug in DBUS... **So for now we MUST** disable apparmor whenever you use tcp=... Bug fix targetted for 14.04

I opened a bug at [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1252821) following discussion [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2013-November/004681.html) with Tyler Hicks:

> The AppArmor mediation code only has the ability to check peer labels
>   over UNIX domain sockets. It is most likely seeing an error when
>   getting the label and then refusing the connection.

Note:
the disable flag  is not recognized by dbus < 1.6.12, so you need to package different versions of mydaemon.conf depending on systen), else dbus-daemon will fail on launch if no apparmor... I used for now in my CMakeLists.txt :

```
IF(EXISTS "/usr/sbin/apparmor_status")
  install(FILES dbus_daemon-apparmordisabled.conf RENAME dbus_daemon.conf DESTINATION /etc/dbus-1/ )
ELSE (EXISTS "/usr/sbin/apparmor_status")
   install(FILES dbus_daemon.conf DESTINATION /etc/dbus-1/ )
ENDIF(EXISTS "/usr/sbin/apparmor_status")
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thanks @Shorin, and another FYI - I had to do something like this to make mine work:

```
<listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=0.0.0.0,port=55884</listen>
```

Note the `bind=0.0.0.0` - the `bind=*` didn't work for me, and I left out the `family=ipv4` part. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I did use netstat on the remote machine to confirm dbus was listening on the port and telnet from local to confirm the port was open.

```
netstat -plntu | grep 55884

tcp   0     0 0.0.0.0:55884    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN    707/dbus-daemon
```

You have to see something like `0 0.0.0.0:55884` and not something like `0 127.0.0.1:55884`.